# C preprocessor expansion order

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to do something using C preprocessor. I have this macros:

```
#define _MAX(x, y) (((x)) > ((y))) ? (x) : (y))

#define MAX1 _MAX(1,
#define MAX2 _MAX(2,0))

#define RIGHT _MAX(1,_MAX(2,0))
#define WRONG MAX1 MAX2
```

In this case, `RIGHT` gives me the right expression but `WRONG`, even though it's the same, expands the macro to blank.

It seems to me that's because after expanding `MAX1` to `_MAX(1,` it detects there is a `_MAX` macro to expand and tries to do it without expanding the `MAX2`, which haves the other half of the statement.

If I'm right, is there any way that I can delay the `_MAX` macro expansion until `MAX2` it's expanded?

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, have you tried defining MAX2 before MAX1 ?

Comment: Note: Adding double parentheses doesn't make the expresssion more secure ;)

Comment: @Neil that didn't work but even if it did I probably couldn't use it in my case, which is a little more complex then that

Comment: With gcc I get `error: unterminated argument list invoking macro "_MAX"`

Comment: I hear inline functions are really nice.

Comment: Such macros as your definition of the `_MAX()` macro are a bad idea because they do not properly handle different types of parameters and do not handle signed values correctly.   Much better to make a `inline` function.  In C, that would be a `inline` function for each variable type to be checked.

Answer (score 3):

It's correct, because of the order `WRONG` is being expanded. First it expands the macro to

```
MAX1 MAX2
```

then it rescans that to expand it further, first it expands `MAX1` to `_MAX(1,` and it's when rescanning this the error occurs as it doesn't find the termination of the argument list.

If you had defined `WRONG` as `MAX1 MAX2 )` it would have expanded it without complaints (but not with the same expansion of course).

Answer (score 3):

C preprocessor scans for macros after each expansion. Section 6.10.3.4 states:

> After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted and `#` and `##` processing has taken place, all placemarker preprocessing tokens are removed. Then, the resulting preprocessing token sequence is rescanned, along with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the source file, for more macro names to replace.

One way to force C preprocessor to expand macro B ahead of macro A is to pass B to A as a parameter:

```
#define _MAX(x, y) (((x)>(y))?(x):(y))

#define MAX1(Y) _MAX(1,Y)
#define MAX2 _MAX(2,0)

#define NEW_RIGHT MAX1(MAX2)
```

Now `MAX2` becomes an argument to `MAX1`, so its content is expanded in the process of expanding `MAX1`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/rLe1Jl)